# Azure AD with Single Page Application and ASP.Net core web api: how to access all relevant tokens?

Tags: azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, azure-ad-msal

Our application is an Angular SPA with ASP.Net Core Web API.  The identity is provided by Microsoft Identity Platform (Azure AD) and authentication is provided by the same.  The authorization is done in Web API basis ["Application Roles"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles#roles-using-azure-ad-app-roles).  These "Application Roles" are held in the Azure AD directory (defined in the Application's manifest and assigned on the tenant domain to users).

The Angular SPA receives the tokens from Azure, as per [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code).  The relevant tokens that are issued are: an `AccessToken` for my Web API (following these [instructions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API)), an `AccessToken` for calling Graph API (following the same [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code)) and an `IdToken` that includes the "Application Roles" as `roles` claim (this id token seems to be included automatically once roles have been assigned).

The problem I face is that I need to pass concurrent tokens to my Web API, but with the HTTP interceptor I can only include 1 token in the header request.  For example, I need the first `AccessToken` to proof authentication to the Web API and I need to include the `IdToken` such that the Web API can perform authorization.

**Q:** How can I call my Web API with multiple tokens, when these tokens are all issued to the SPA and need to be included in the HTTP call to my Web API?

Comment: Why do you acquire access token from Microsoft Graph API? You want to get Graph data in your ASP.Net Core Web API application? Or you just want to get the id token from Microsoft Graph?

Comment: I had planned to get access to the Graph API in my Web API.

Comment: OK. Please follow my suggestions in the answer. To call Microsoft Graph in API, you should consider OBO auth flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at OBO for accessing the Graph API.

Comment: Sample project for OBO: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter whether you want to get Microsoft Graph data, the way you used to get Application role is incorrect.

An id token cannot be used to perform authorization for your Web API application. You have to use access token. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268984/authentication-to-azure-ad-protected-app-using-id-token?answertab=votes#tab-top) to learn about the usage of id token and access token.

So you have to use an access token rather than id token.

In this case, you configure the app roles in the Azure AD app which represents Angular SPA (the front).

In fact, you should configure the app roles in the Azure AD app which represents ASP.Net Core Web API (the backend). Then you can get the "Application Roles" as `roles` claim in the AccessToken for your Web API.

Comment: Thanks, I will configure the App Roles on the Web API registration instead!

Comment: @Superman.Lopez np:) Don't forget to assign users to the app roles during your test.

Comment: Managed to implement both the Application Roles and the On-Behalf-Of call to Graph API, thanks again for your help!